# Как сделать мгновенный переход к телеграмм боту с сайта?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, при переходе на телеграмм бота с сайта сначала открывается сайт телеграмма, а потом уже сам бот. Как сделать так, чтобы сразу открывался телеграмм бот?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте ссылку вида `tg://resolve?domain=botname`.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!